# How to re-submit removed android apps to google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

My apps have been removed from Google Play due to failure to accept the latest version of the Developer Distribution Agreement long time ago. Now I have accepted the agreement and need to republish it. But I couldn't do that.

The warning message says "Your apps were removed from the Play Store due to failure to accept the new Developer Distribution Agreement prior to the deadline. All functionality for existing users (if applicable) has been disabled. Now that you have accepted the agreement, you can re-submit your apps". So how can I resubmit?

I've tried to resubmit but found no button where to resubmit my apps. Is there anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ then upload your new APK

Comment: Can you offer some background information - why did you not meet the deadline for accepting the agreement?

Comment: i lost my password that time and this is not important now can you answer my question. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to upload it as a new app you just need to fix the reason(s) that your app was removed for. In my case my app was removed because I didn't fill the app content section and after I added it now my app shows "Processing update" and once it's approved by the "The Google Play Team" they will put it live again.

## Check the email that they sent you it contains the removal reason(s)

1. Just fix the problem
2. Check if it shows "Processing update" on the "Dashboard" section
3. Then wait until they approve it
4. If they reject the update they will send you a new email about the new reason(s)

Good luck

Comment: how long does it to be available on the store again. for my case it was  the long description, I fixed it and a button submit app appeared. I clicked it and im still waiting , it's been two days . and i don't see processing update .

Answer (score 1):

Your old apk has been removed so open the play console of your app and try uploading new apk like you did before and change the version code and version name and publish it like a new app (but with same package name).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. but when i upload as new is that mean all of my previous rate and review disappeared. my apps had more than 50k download hundreds of review and many rate nearly 4 . so is that mean when i change now version name and number i will start from scratch with zero review and comment or number of user that download? please comment! thanks

Comment: yes.Indeed you will have to start from scratch.But this is the only way to resubmit the app removed from google playstore.If you find this helpful please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The button is now located in the Publishing overview section:

[image]